# How do I get a checkbox and text on the same line in a Mailchimp embedded form?

Tags: html, css, email

I am styling a Mailchimp form with groups and am having problems with the checkboxes being on one line and the text being on the next in an unordered list. You can see it on this page:

http://www.warmheartspublishing.com/newsletter/

Both the checkbox and text are within the same LI tag, so I don't know why the text is being bumped down below the checkbox. By the way, I'm using the Genesis framework.

Here's the code for the form that I'm putting in Wordpress:

```
<div id="mailchimp">
<form action="//warmheartspublishing.us13.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=74d56fdb848e8be499cc4df0e&amp;id=fd37fb691f" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
<div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
<p style="text-align: center;">Sign up to get news on sales, products, and freebies</p>
<div class="indicates-required" style="font-size: 10px;"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">


<input type="text" value="First Name" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
</div>

<div class="mc-field-group">
    <input type="text" value="Last Name" name="LNAME" class="" id="mce-LNAME" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <input type="email" value="E-mail Address *" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group input-group">
    <p>What areas are you interested in? </p>
    <ul><li><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group[2381][1]" id="mce-group[2381]-2381-0"><label for="mce-group[2381]-2381-0">Early Learning</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="group[2381][2]" id="mce-group[2381]-2381-1"><label for="mce-group[2381]-2381-1">Kindergarten</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="group[2381][4]" id="mce-group[2381]-2381-2"><label for="mce-group[2381]-2381-2">Grades 1 - 3</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="8" name="group[2381][8]" id="mce-group[2381]-2381-3"><label for="mce-group[2381]-2381-3">Grades 4 - 6</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="16" name="group[2381][16]" id="mce-group[2381]-2381-4"><label for="mce-group[2381]-2381-4">Grades 7 - 8</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="32" name="group[2381][32]" id="mce-group[2381]-2381-5"><label for="mce-group[2381]-2381-5">Grades 9 - 12</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="64" name="group[2381][64]" id="mce-group[2381]-2381-6"><label for="mce-group[2381]-2381-6">Language Arts</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="128" name="group[2381][128]" id="mce-group[2381]-2381-7"><label for="mce-group[2381]-2381-7">Math</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="256" name="group[2381][256]" id="mce-group[2381]-2381-8"><label for="mce-group[2381]-2381-8">Science</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="512" name="group[2381][512]" id="mce-group[2381]-2381-9"><label for="mce-group[2381]-2381-9">History &amp; Geography</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="1024" name="group[2381][1024]" id="mce-group[2381]-2381-10"><label for="mce-group[2381]-2381-10">Foreign Language</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="2048" name="group[2381][2048]" id="mce-group[2381]-2381-11"><label for="mce-group[2381]-2381-11">Music &amp; Drama</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="4096" name="group[2381][4096]" id="mce-group[2381]-2381-12"><label for="mce-group[2381]-2381-12">Visual Arts</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="8192" name="group[2381][8192]" id="mce-group[2381]-2381-13"><label for="mce-group[2381]-2381-13">Phy. Ed. &amp; Health</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="16384" name="group[2381][16384]" id="mce-group[2381]-2381-14"><label for="mce-group[2381]-2381-14">Religious</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" value="32768" name="group[2381][32768]" id="mce-group[2381]-2381-15"><label for="mce-group[2381]-2381-15">Everything</label></li>
</ul>
</div>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_74d56fdb848e8be499cc4df0e_fd37fb691f" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
<p style="font-size: 12px;">We respect your privacy</p>
</form>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS setup for the Mailchimp form:

```
#mailchimp {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #F23D4F;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #F23D4F;
    width: 335px;
}
#mailchimp input {
    border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #F23D4F;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 8px 10px;
        width: 300px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 10px;

}

#mailchimp input[type="submit"] {
    background: #F23D4F;
    color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #F23D4F;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 35%;
    padding: 8px 0;

        }
#mailchimp input[type="submit"]:hover { 
    color: #F23D4F;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #F23D4F;
}

#mailchimp div.mc-field-group.input-group ul li {
    list-style-type: none;

}
```

Here's a picture of what it's doing.

[image: Signup form glitch]

Answer (score 0):

You change this CSS rule

```
#mailchimp div.mc-field-group.input-group ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;                                    /* added */
}
```

Comment: That with a bit of margin adjustments did it. Thanks LGSon!